# Haskell - Concatenation of Lists

Tags: haskell

i try to concatenate two lists such that the elements in the resulting list occurs only once.
i didnt want to use a predefined function because then it would be too easy. so because of i am learning haskell i write the following code:

```
import Data.List

add :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]

add xs ys = zs ++ ws
        where
        zs = if elem x (x:xs) == True then x:(elem x xs)
             else elem x xs
        ws = if elem y (y:ys) == True then y:(elem y ys)
             else elem y ys
```

i only use the predefined function elem which tells me if an element occurs in the list.
my idea was to take one list first and use "elem" to find out if the first element x of the list xs exists in the list more than once. If that so, then i take that x and with ":"-operator and (elem x xs)  i build up a new list until all elements are checked.
The same thing i do with the second list. 
If is done, then i use "++" - operator to concatenate the duplicate-free lists with zs ++ ws. So when I compile it, then ghci tells me that x and y are not in scope. Where i my mistake ?

Comment: Things are quite confused here. For example, the type of `elem x xs` is `Bool`, so the expression `x:(elem x xs)` doesn't make any sense. Moreover, the term `x` appears out of nowhere - you haven't defined what it is.

Comment: Well, `x` and `y` are indeed not in scope, you don't define them anywhere before using them. In your mind, what are `x` and `y` supposed to be? Maybe you meant for your pattern matching to be `add (x:xs) (y:ys)`?

Comment: With elem x (x:xs) i try to express, that i check if the first element of the list xs occurs in the list more than once. Therefore, x and y should be the first elements of the lists xs and ys.

Comment: No, `x` and `y` are the first elements of the lists `x:xs` and `y:ys`.

Answer (score 8):

You haven't given examples of the expected input/output of this function, so I'll work with the definition that you gave -

> "Concatenate two lists such that the elements in the resulting list occur only once."

It seems like there's a straightforward way to do this -

1. Concatenate the two lists.
2. Remove the duplicates.

So let's assume you have a function `unique :: [Int] -> [Int]` that removes duplicates from a list (while keeping the elements in order). Then what you want is as simple as

```
add :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
add xs ys = unique (xs ++ ys)
```

so you've reduced the problem to the simpler one of writing the `unique` function. Can you do that?

Answer (score 6):

I think Chris's solution is the way to go. But for the sake of teaching, I will discuss some of the problems in your approach. First of all, in order to reference `x` and `y` in your function `add`, they must be defined somewhere. I suspect what you intended was:

```
add (x:xs) (y:ys) = ...
```

Now you can use `x`, `xs`, `y` and `ys` in your function definition. Now any time you're tempted to write something like:

```
if condition == True then...
```

know that it's simpler and clearer to just write

```
if condition then...
```

So I think you were intending to write something kind of like this:

```
add (x:xs) (y:ys) = zs ++ ws
    where
        zs = if elem x xs then xs
                          else x:xs
        ws = if elem y ys then ys
                          else y:ys
```

except that you also wanted to do some sort of *recursion* to make sure that none of the elements in `xs` or `ys` is repeated. However, recursing down two lists would be very awkward and difficult to do. That's why Chris's answer is better, and the more Haskell-y way to approach it.

Note also that instead of

```
elem x xs
```

it can be more readable to write

```
x `elem` xs
```

Comment: What is more, `elem x xs` and `elem x ys` will both have to be checked. Same goes for `y`.